# I am trying to read a stream request sent from another Servlet in Struts2

Tags: servlets, struts2, request

I am trying to write a servlet that will send a XML file (xml formatted string) to another servlet via a POST in STRUTS2.

servlet that will send a XML file:

```
String requestStr = "...........xml text........";    
URLConnection con = new uRL("http://192.168.1.74/Project1/Request").openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream xmlResp = con.getOutputStream();
xmlResp.write(requestStr.getBytes("UTF-8"));
xmlResp.flush();
xmlResp.close();
```

servlet that will recive a XML file :

```
 InputStream in=req.getInputStream();
  StringBuffer xmlStr=new StringBuffer();
    int d;
    while((d=in.read()) != -1){
              xmlStr.append((char)d);
    }
    System.out.println("xmlStr1--"+xmlStr.toString());
    int iCont=req.getContentLength();
    return xmlStr.toString();
```

in above case InputStream : in.read returns -1 but int iCont = req.getContentLength(); iCont returns value 1335....!

Above code worked fine when checked in non-struts Environment.....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved :
If you are using inputStream in srvlet to read value stream, you are not suppose to use `Request.getParameter()`.... before getting Stream value to InputStream through `req.getInputStream()`...

Ex:

Correct-- method

```
InputStream in=req.getInputStream();
  StringBuffer xmlStr=new StringBuffer();
    int d;
    while((d=in.read()) != -1){
              xmlStr.append((char)d);
    }
    System.out.println("xmlStr1--"+xmlStr.toString());
```

Below method will cause ISSUE:

```
String str = req.getParameter("SOMETEXT");

InputStream in=req.getInputStream();
  StringBuffer xmlStr=new StringBuffer();
    int d;
    while((d=in.read()) != -1){
              xmlStr.append((char)d);
    }
    System.out.println("xmlStr1--"+xmlStr.toString());
```